# Please clarify - What's my default site?

Tags: joomla, themes, customization

I've just installed Joomla and I'm a little confused with the new interface.

I'm actually looking at Joomla after about 2 years.

I've installed it and it has things like default pages about joomla, Australian Parks and Fruits...

Now, are these separate sites or are they just a heap of pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the default data during the installation process. This demo data is intended to show you the features of Joomla and how it works. To stop it from showing start the installation and on the last step you will be asked to enter the admin password and the site name... don't click on "Install Sample Data" and your Joomla installation will be plain waiting for you to load the contents!

Comment: Thanks Ahmad Alfy. So that all ONE site of sample data or are they many? I noticed one about a FUIT SHOP, PARK and JOOMLA

Comment: This is all just one simple site with dummy data